# As put where if the variable is greater than the condition?

Tags: php, mysql, date, where-clause

I have two tables, one where you last put into the site, and the other with messages and date. The problem is that when I check with PHP for messages with the date greater than the last time I get between 6 Messages with past dates.

Tables MYSQL:

**Chatgr**(Messages)

---

id (Id of Message)|Nametable (Id of the group)|text(Message)|idusuario (Id of user)|date|

**gruposadd**(Other table with last put into the site)

---

idgroup(Id of the group)|iduser(Id of user)|state|date|

Code PHP:

```
$group = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gruposadd WHERE iduser='$_SESSION[id]' AND state='1'"); 
while ($groups = mysql_fetch_array($group)) {
$smsgr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chatgr WHERE nametable='$groups[idgroup]' AND date>'$groups[date]'"); 
while ($listasgr = mysql_fetch_array($smsgr)) { ....
```

Comment: Please, do not use `mysql_*` functions in your new code - they are deprecated. And double cycle? Why do not use `JOIN` instead, grouping by desired field?

Comment: There is no clear indication of what you're trying to ask here...

Comment: what does `$groups[date]` look like and whats the column type of `date`

Comment: $ groups [date] is the result of the first query that displays the date of the last time into the site